# My extension for Google Chrome that blocks website, doesn't work on youtube, but on every other website it works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

## Description

I made this extension for google chrome, which blocks website by keyword and is working perfectly on all websites, but on youtube it doesn't work.

Is there any solution so that my extension works on youtube as well?

### background.js

```js
console.log("Loaded extension");



function blockRequest(details) {
   return {cancel: true};
}
function updateFilters(urls) {
   if(chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.hasListener(blockRequest))
     chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blockRequest);
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockRequest, {
      urls: [
         "https://*/*"+ "mrbeast*"
         ]
   }, 
   ['blocking']);
}
updateFilters();
```

### maninfest.json

```json
{
  "name": "Foco Study",
  "description": "Foco",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
     "webRequestBlocking",
     "webRequest",
     "activeTab",
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*",
     "https://www.youtube.com/*"
  ],
  "background" : {
    "scripts":  [
      
      "background.js"
    ],
    "matches": [
      "*://www.youtube.com/*", "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: 1) Open `chrome://policy` and see if it has ExtensionSettings with youtube inside. 2) Open `chrome://apps` and remove the app for youtube. 3) Open `chrome://extensions` and reload the extension.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't work

Comment: See https://crbug.com/1175349: you should use chrome.browsingData to clear the cache for youtube.

Comment: How to implement chrome.browsing Data to clear in my code?

Comment: See the documentation and examples. You'll need to specify `cache`, `cacheStorage`, `serviceWorkers`.

Comment: `chrome.browsingData.remove({
  "origins": ["https://www.youtube.com"]
}, {
  "cacheStorage": true,
  "serviceWorkers": true
}, callback);`

Comment: Just add this code in background.js?